# Prove that determining whether a Turing machine ends in polynomial time on any input is undecidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I'd like to prove by reduction that given a Turing machine $M$, there exists no Turing machine that decides whether $M$ ends in polynomial time on any input.

Any idea as to what problem to reduce, as a first hint?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Have you tried the Halting problem as default reduction partner? You may want to check out [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/847/98), and [this one](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5004/1546).

Comment: What does "ends in polynomial time on any input" mean? Polynomial time is an asymptotic notion, and we usually don't have a fixed polynomial in mind. Try to rephrase your question using more basic terms.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus \*shrug\* "... no Turing machine that decides whether there is some polynomial $p$ such that $M$ halts within $p(|x|)$ steps for all inputs $x$." I suspect that's not the asker's difficulty.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In that case, perhaps *every* is better than *any*.

Comment: Hint: Reduce from the halting problem on an empty tape.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yeah. I vote to ban the word "any" in mathematical writing. It can be existential or universal depending on context and it's far too easy to interpret it the wrong way. (Actually, I think that, in this case, I might've misread the question as literally saying "every"; I agree that it looks existential in the actual sentence.)

Comment: If you want to improve your question, please *edit* it! Click the link beneath the question, it'll take you to the edit form.

Comment: It would be easier to prove this using Rice's Theorem. Moreover, such a proof would easily generalize to arbitrary complexity classes (for time complexity as well as for space complexity).